# asp:GridView - change checkbox status when click anywhere in the line

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a web app and use gridview to show some SQL data. In the GV I have a checkbox in the first column. As suggested in the title, I want to check the checkbox when user clicks anywhere in that line. How can I accomplish that. Thanks.

This is my GV;

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"
            OnRowDataBound="myGV_OnRowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="myCB" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" />
```

I use this code to highlight the row when mouse pointer is over it;

```
protected void myGV_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.originalstyle=this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor='#D9ECFB'");
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=this.originalstyle;");
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I added "OnSelectedIndexChanging" and "OnSelectedIndexChanged" to the GridView and then tried this (as suggested by Ravi), but couldn't get it to work.

```
protected void myGV_SelectedIndexChanging(Object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = myGV.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];

    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)myGV.FindControl("cbIzpis");

    if (chk.Checked == true)
    {
        chk.Checked = false;
    }
    else if (chk.Checked == false)
    {
        chk.Checked = true;
    }
}

protected void myGV_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = nyGV.SelectedRow;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use GridView.SelectedRow property, with SelectedIndexChanged Event, [Gridview Selected Row](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow.aspx)

```
 void CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    // Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property.
    GridViewRow row = CustomersGridView.SelectedRow;
    MessageLabel.Text = "You selected " + row.Cells[2].Text + ".";

  }

  void CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanging(Object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
  {

    // SelectedIndexChanging event occurs before the select operation in the GridView control, the
    // SelectedRow property cannot be used. Instead, use the Rows collection
    // and the NewSelectedIndex property of the e argument passed to this 
    // event handler.
    GridViewRow row = CustomersGridView.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];
    // here you can check the checkbox, by accessing it in template column using findControl method 
     CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) CustomersGridview.FindControl("chkboxID"); 
    chk.checked;    


    if (row.Cells[1].Text == "SomeCondition")
    {

      e.Cancel = true;
      MessageLabel.Text = "You cannot select " + row.Cells[2].Text + ".";

    }

  }
```

Comment: it didn't work. :( I edited the question with the code I tried. Can you check if you see the problem?

Comment: no error. when I clicked on any row, nothing happened. no errors or anything

Comment: you try to set autogenerateselectbutton=true in Gridview. as i checked here it is working.

Comment: sorry, was busy with other stuff, so couldn't reply sooner. No problem, even if I don't find a way to make it work, it would be just a bonus functionality. :) Thanx for your help, will try implementing it when I have little more time.